# WordPress not recognizing user is logged in

Tags: wordpress

I want ONLY users who are logged in to view my WordPress site and the code I'm using is:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'admin_redirect');
function admin_redirect() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in()) {
        auth_redirect();
   }
}
```

**PROMLEM:** if I send a hyperlink every time the user clicks it they are asked to sign in again.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of `auth_redirect()`, you shouldn't have to place that check around it. The function actually handles that check itself as shown in the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/auth_redirect)

Also, I'd recommend moving this function into your header. By simply calling `auth_redirect()` in your header (which should be called on each and every page anyways), you can check if the user is logged in. If not, they should be bounced to the wp-login page.

Edit:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
  is_user_logged_in() || auth_redirect();
});
```

The folks over at the WordPress Exchange are much better with this sort of stuff. Found this link [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76359/website-visible-only-to-registered-users/76363#76363).

Comment: I disabled my plugin added auth_redirect() to the header and it redirected everyone to the login page.

Comment: And after logging in, it still sends users to the login page?

Comment: Yes it did. I'm thinking the hook is being executed before wordpress sets the login status

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just put

```
auth_redirect();
```

into your functions.php file?

This should redirect users who aren't logged in to the log in page but remember which page they were trying to access. Then when they log in it should redirect them to their destination page.

Is this not working?